# How to import netbeans project to eclipse ignoring package declaration?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide

I have a (legacy) `netbeans` project that I'd like to import and maintain in `eclipse`. For the sake of it I have to provide backwards compatibility with the netbeans project recourses.

Problem: the source folders have the hirarchie `src/java/de/mycompany/...`, but the classes themself have the following package imports:

```
package de.mycompany; //error

public class MainClass {

}
```

When opening the project in netbeans the IDE does *not* complain about that package source mismatch. But eclipse does:

`Error: The declared package "de.mycompany" does not match the expected package "java.de.mycompany"`.

Question: how can I overcome this, if possible at all?
I cannot move the java classes do the "right" package as the declaration of the packages have to be left untouched also for compatibility reasons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the source folders in Eclipse.

1. Right-click on the project and select `Properties`
2. Navigate to `Java Build Path`
3. Open the `Source` tab
4. Click on the `Add Source` button and then select the `src/java` folder in order to add it as a source folder.

You will probably note that this change actually adds a `classpathentry` entry within the Eclipse specific `.classpath` file.

A *project* in the context of NetBeans has a different structure than a project in Eclipse. That's why using maven (with the corresponding IDE plugins) can be helpful here.

Comment: I'd love to have a `maven` project here for portability. Unfortunately it's just a plain old netbeans...